# Failed to mount local volume with relative path

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Per [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) relative hosts paths can be used using `.` and `..` notation. For example it states

> Relative host paths MUST only be supported by Compose implementations
> that deploy to a local container runtime. This is because the relative
> path is resolved from the Compose file’s parent directory which is
> only applicable in the local case.

On my Ubuntu 18.04 desktop running Docker compose v2.5.0 and Docker 20.10.16 this however is not / no longer the case. Docker compose fails with

> Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume
> '/var/lib/docker/volumes/log/_data': failed to mount local volume:
> mount ./log:/var/lib/docker/volumes/log/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such
> file or directory

The log directory however does exist. It is in the same directory as the Docker compose file.

Why is Docker compose unable to find this directory? What are the requirements and what is supported when it comes to mounting host directories?

```bash
[onknows:~/git/github/cnl] [2.5.3] develop(+3/-4,4) ± tree -L 1
.
├── config
├── docker-compose.yml
├── log
└── ops
```

```yaml
volumes:
  log:
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: ./log
      o: bind
```

Comment: What's actually in your `docker-compose.yml` file?  Seeing a `/var/lib/docker` path looks odd to me, since that's usually used for named volumes and not bind mounts.

Comment: Both named volumes and bind mounts are in there. The error is for a named volume.

Comment: Can you update the question to show both your `docker-compose.yaml` as well as the output of something like `tree` showing the directory layout?

Answer (score 1):

```yaml
volumes:
  log:
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: ./log # this won't work
      o: bind
```

When you specify a volume like this, it gets passed directly to the mount system call, which requires a full path. To use a relative path, define the service with a host volume:

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  test:
    image: busybox
    volumes:
      - "./log:/app/log"
```